# Is there any way to change $? from a zle widget?

Tags: zsh, zle

I have a widget for mapping `^Z` to `fg`:

```
function ctrlz() {
    [[ $(jobs | wc -l) > 0 ]] && {
        zle -I
        fg
    }
}
```

However, since widgets can't change `$?`, the exit status of the `fg` is ignored. An alternative approach of `zle push-line; BUFFER="fg"; zle accept-line` also works somewhat, but it adds an extra line (with prompt + `fg`) in the terminal output, as well as adding `fg` to history (even with `HIST_NO_STORE` set).

Is there any way to make a widget run `fg` *with* affecting `$?`, but *without* any unnecessary output (the `[1]  + continued python` is bad enough) or history entries?